# Google Drive - Get rootFolder ID by users email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps-for-education

We want to push copies of our school's materials to the students own "My Drive" folders.

The below script works well, and nicely puts a link of the source folder in the students "Shared with me" folder.

```
function setPermissions(){
var id = "SOURCE_FOLDER_ID"
var firstGet = DriveApp.getFolderById(id)
var folder = firstGet.getId()

 Drive.Permissions.insert(
 {
 'role': 'writer',
 'type': 'user',
 'value': 'TARGET_USER_EMAIL',
  }, 
 folder,
       {
       'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'       
      });
}
```

However, these are young students about 8 or 9 years old and we want to the project folders we make to end up in their "My Drive" location without further click from the student's side.

I know we can use [addFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addfolderchild) to put the folders into the student's Google Drive root folder.

However, this means knowing the student's root folder ID.

Does anyone know how can I get the student's root folder IDs by iterating through their email addresses?

Google [has documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get#request-body) on how to get the current users rood folder, but I want to get the root folder ids of all the student's in the class.

Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting permissions -- `Drive.Permissions.insert()` -- you're sharing the file, so the default location would be "Shared with me", so you'll need to move the file after you share it.

An alternative approach, which is what i think you want from your question, is to use `Drive.Files.copy()`, which will put a copy if the item into a folder specified in the `parents[]` property. Not setting the `parents[]` array in the request body will set the destination to the account's Google Drive root.